# Tense in "I hoped to spend time with my father while I am on vacation"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> I hoped to spend time with my father while I am on vacation.

Since it should be in past tense, is it correct to use "am"?

Comment: Is the vacation in the future or the past?

Comment: One complication is that people rarely speak of hoping as an instantaneous event in the past. For the most part, English speakers would say "had hoped" to indicate a more-or-less continuous action in the past (no specific instant). If the vacation is still in the future, the best way to say it might be "I hope to" because that hope persists through the present. Can you write more about the situation itself and the context in which you are writing about it?

Comment: *Had hoped* isn't any more or less continuous than *hoped*. Was/had been hoping is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your vacation was in the past, so -

> I had hoped to spend time with my father while I *was* on vacation.

Would be the correct usage in my opinion.